# How to extract valueform the loggroup so that it can be plotted in a graph widget in AWS Dashboard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to get the sum of all the successes and sum of all the successes_after_retry which comes from the AWS loggroup and plot it in a grapgh widget in aws dashboard. I am not sure how to use the metric filter pattern to extract the values.

```
2023-11-01T23:50:46.010Z    824e130b-ffa9-4d81-88e0-95ab1116ec91    INFO    randomID - someDestination{
  message: 'Delivery Metrics',
  sourceName: ‘test ‘Source,
  sourceId: ‘randomID’,
  destinationId: ‘randomDestID’,
  destinationName: ‘someDestination’,
  metrics: {
    successes: 3000,
    successes_on_first_attempt: 2000,
    successes_after_retry: 1000,
    expired: 0,
    discarded: 0,
    retried: 0,
    time_to_success: 0,
    time_to_success_average: 0,
    time_to_success_p95: 0,
    time_to_first_attempt: 0,
    time_to_first_attempt_average: 0,
    time_to_first_attempt_p95: 0
  },
  successRate: 100
}
```

Comment: You'll have a hard time because that's a weird message format - neither JSON nor comma-delimited, both of which cloudwatch supports natively.

Comment: My work around was to stringify the logs and use the returnValue and assign properties to it.